# Is Zorich a good self-study books for second and third real analysis courses?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, reference-request, book-recommendation

I've been using Stephen Abbott's *Understanding Analysis* as a complement to my first real analysis course and it's been very helpful. Now, I've looked into the contents of Vladimir Zorich's *Mathematical Analysis I & II* and they seem to span the entire syllabus of my undergrad real analysis courses.

Would you recommend Zorich as an accompaniment to a lectures-based course, for self-study and reinforcement of the material? People have been warning me about Rudin so I'm wary of buying it, and I like the style of Russian mathematicians. Or maybe it's a tad too formal for first-year undergrads, and there are friendlier books out there?

Opinions on the matter would be very helpful.

Comment: I don’t think you can understand anything from Rudin. You can understand every step of the proofs, but you do not learn anything. Zorich is a real book, good for self-study. It even has sentences not belonging to a formal definition or proof.

Comment: Pugh’s book is also good.

Comment: Try Lang's "Undergraduate Analysis". It isn't very expensive and may be available as a .pdf.

Comment: Strichartz "Way of Analysis" is by far the friendliest analysis text. Though you may find how friendly it is to be very annoying...